# How to add a string of variable into data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How to add a column, which a predefined string of factors as a fourth column into  anexisting data frame.

I have a tibble of 5X3 .,

I want to add a string of variables `status <- c(0,0,1,1,0)` as  a fourth column. 
How can I do that?

```
# New column to add
status<- c(0,0,1,1,0)

# dataset
test<- structure(list(id = 1:5, weight = 63:67, height = 171:175), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `test$status<- c(0,0,1,1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
status<- c(0,0,1,1,0)

test %>% 
  mutate(status = status)
```

Or you can use `bind_cols`:

```
test %>% bind_cols(status = status)
```

Or simply

```
test$status <- status
```